# How do I get Object out of HashMap?

Tags: java, object, hashmap

Im trying to get an object out of a HashMap and call a method from this object.
But insted of getting the object, I get a normal `java.lang.Object`.

```
public void setExits(HashMap<Direction, Exit> e){
        this.exits = e;

        Iterator it = e.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry exits = (Map.Entry) it.next();
            Exit r = exits.getValue(); //HERE I GET ERROR
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can cast the object to the class type which you use when putting it into hashmap.

Comment: Try casting the object to Exit like so:

    Exit r = (Exit) exits.getValue();

Comment: why not get the typed object?         Iterator<Exit> it = e.entrySet().iterator();

Comment: Map.Entry doesn't have a type defined so it assumes its an Object. That will need to be casted to (Exit)

Answer (score 3):

You are declaring type constraints in the method signature but in the method body you are not taking any advantage of using the type constraints.

What you are doing is similar to you are using HashMap< Object, Object >. That is why compile error.

Correct Code:

```
public void setExits(HashMap<Direction, Exit> e){
    this.exits = e;
    Iterator<Map.Entry<Direction, Exit>> it = e.entrySet().iterator();

    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<Direction, Exit> entry = it.next();

        Exit r = entry.getValue(); // OK
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this line:

```
Iterator it = e.entrySet().iterator();
```

to:

```
Iterator<Entry<Direction, Exit>> it = e.entrySet().iterator();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I might iterate every value in a `HashMap`

```
HashMap<Directive, Exit> tempHashMap = new HashMap<>();
        for(Directive directive:tempHashMap.keySet()){
            Exit tempExit = tempHashMap.get(directive);
            //do what you want with the exit
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `HashMap` like a list.  It's not a very effective list.

Instead do

```
 Object value = map.get(key);
```

And it will skip the items that aren't under the key, very efficiently.

```
public void setExits(HashMap<Direction, Exit> exits, Direction direction){
    this.exits = e.get(direction);
}
```

Comment: I need to iterate over the HashMap tho because I need to do something to each set.

Answer (score 0):

What you have missed is the generics for the Map.Entry.

It looks to me as though you are trying to loop over all the entries of the map, you might find a for loop easier.

```
for(Map.Entry<Direction, Exit> entry : e.entrySet()) {
    Direction dir = entry.value();
    //do stuff
}
```